# Gcloud database-migration migration-jobs create broken argument

Tags: database, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, database-migration, gcloud

Trying to write a script to bulk create migration jobs using the cloud command. I have created the source and destination connection profile successfully but when creating the job I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.database-migration.migration-jobs.create) FAILED_PRECONDITION: The specified connection profile 'projects/<project_name>/locations/us-central1/connectionProfiles/cp2' does not exist, please create it first, and then try again
```

Here are the commands I am running

```
gcloud database-migration connection-profiles create postgresql cp1 --region=us-central1 --password=test!  --username=postgres --display-name=migration-test --host=10.119.0.206 --port=5432 --cloudsql-instance=migration-test

gcloud database-migration connection-profiles create postgresql cp2 --region=us-central1 --password=test!  --username=postgres --display-name=migration-test-new --host=10.119.0.253 --port=5432 --cloudsql-instance=migration-test-new

gcloud database-migration migration-jobs create migration-test --region=us-central1 --display-name=hello --source=cp1  --destination=cp2 --type=CONTINUOUS
```

Answer (score 0):

A destination database instance has to be of 'cloudsql' kind, which can be created using 'gcloud database-migration connection-profiles create cloudsql' - so you cannot use an existing database as a target, you have to let DMS create it.

This is not really explicitly emphasised in the documentation, but the web based console is also constructed this way, and the API examples also show this as a usecase: https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/postgres/api-connection-profiles#create_a_connection_profile_for_for_destination

The error message is not very informative indeed.